# How to receive notifications on servers side

Tags: .net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm sending notification from server side C# to clients like Web Browsers and Mobile Apps (Android) is there a way to receive this notification from another App on another server?

In other words can I send notification from one server and receive it in another server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging is only designed for messaging between server and mobile apps.  It's not for server to server messaging.  Server messaging is typically implemented using API endpoints, or a message queue like [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/).